# How to copy file to another folder using cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Currently I'm using the code below to try and make a batch file to automatically copy the file to my 'test location' folder.

```
xcopy "C:\Users\MyComputer\Desktop\Excel.xlsx" "C:\Users\MyComputer\Desktop\test location\Excel.xlsx"
```

However it doesn't seem to be working. I picked up the code online and made my own modifications. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your command is syntactically correct. What you are probably missing is to have mentioned the error message you observed. In all probability, you don't have a directory named `mycomputer` within `users` and you should try replacing `mycomputer` with *your user name*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-check the name of your destination folder to make sure you aren't missing an underscore or something. Then try removing `\Excel.xlsx` from the end of your destination specification and see if it works:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\MyComputer\Desktop\Excel.xlsx" "C:\Users\MyComputer\Desktop\test location"
```